# Prevent ResizeEnd event from resetting the window size

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I have a Window that gets resized by code upon an external event. The external event indicates that new data is available and the form needs to resize slightly to fit the new data. This works fine in the normal case BUT when holding down the mouse of the window title bar, the window is resized back to the original size after releasing the mouse. Let me explain:

1. Window has size X
2. Pressing mouse down on the window title bar
3. External event is received, Window is resized to Y. This works fine and the window is correctly resized and redrawn.
4. Releasing mouse on the window title bar causes an ResizeEnd evnet to be triggered which resizes the window back to X.

How do I prevent the window from being resized back to X in ResizeEnd event in the best way?

Comment: You'll have to use the ResizeBegin and ResizeEnd events to detect that the user is busy moving or resizing the window.  And delay the resize until ResizeEnd fires.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid that was the case....